# rails 3 :include with find()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model User which has_many :messages and Message which belong_to :user.

when I do Message.find(1, :include => :user) it doesn't return me user but if I do Message.find(1).to_json(:include => :user) it does include the user object in the hash.

How can I get it include it in Message.find(1, :include => :user) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a case of eager/lazy loading. When you do:

```
Message.find(1, :include => :user)
```

You are eagerly loading the user, becuase when you call `@message.user`, you aren't making another query to fetch the user, whereas doing:

```
Message.find(1)
```

Will find the message, and calling `@message.user` will make another SQL query(aka lazy loading).

If you look at the actual SQL queries getting sent to the server, you will see that you are infact fetching the user in the first example.

The reason why it isn't showing is because when you inspect `@message` it just shows the message, as opposed to calling `to_json`, which forces the inspection of `user`.

Comment: If i call to_json it will escape the " (quote). Can I not escape the quotes?

Answer (score 3):

It is included, so if you call this:

```
@message = Message.find(1, :include => :user)
@message.user
```

Second query won't be executed because user is already loaded, while

```
@message = Message.find(1)
@message.user
```

will execute both queries

And useful screencast to understand what is going on

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading

Comment: I'm using rails console to see if it returns the object with user in it. It doesn't show it there. Should it not show it there? @message.user does work.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is capable with rails 4.

```
Message.includes(:user).find(1)
```

Comment: Not really. '.find' is deprecated in Rails 4. You need 
    Message.includes(:user).where(id: 1).first

Answer (score 2):

It is included in the SQL query. When you will call `Message.find(1, :include => :user).user` no query will be executed for that. All of the data is loaded in one SQL query.

Watch application log for evidence (`tail -f log/development.log`).